# JACKSON JSON deserialization issue with overrloaded setter

Tags: java, json, jackson, jsonschema

From several reasons we have to make for developers convenience be able to set the one reference via overloaded setters ( this due it is modelled as oneOf attribute).

I would expect that depending on the JSON schema the polymorphic (oneOf) property would have the deserialized reference to object of FooType or BarType, ....

depending on the JSON schema.
I was hoping since FooType , BarType follow bean convention they can be easily determined like it happens for JacksonFeature in JAXRS ....

In my dummy test it seems to not work as described below :

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
    mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
    mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
    mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.READ_ENUMS_USING_TO_STRING, true);
    mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_ENUMS_USING_TO_STRING, true);

 mapper.readValue(SCHEMA, SimplePojo.class);
```

The issue is that the mapper crashes, and JSON schema(SCH1) can not be deserialized to POJO

The JSON schema (SCH1)

```
{
"dummy" : {
"bar" : "bar",
"baz" : 10
},
"other" : {
"foo" : "hi there"
},
"simple" : "simple"
}
```

The sub element types dummy, other look like :

```
public class BarType {

private String bar;

private Number baz;

public String getBar() {
    return bar;
}

public void setBar(String bar) {
    this.bar = bar;
}

public Number getBaz() {
    return baz;
}

public void setBaz(Number baz) {
    this.baz = baz;
}
```

and

```
 public class FooType {

private Object foo;

public Object getFoo() {
    return foo;
}

public void setFoo(Object foo) {
    this.foo = foo;
}
```

The top level POJO ( i skipped some part )

```
public class SimplePojo {

private String simpleField;

private Object dummyField;

private Object otherField;

public String getSimple() {
    return simpleField;
}

public void setSimple(String simple) {
    this.simpleField = simple;
}

...
public void setDummy(final FooType dummy) {
    this.dummyField = dummy;
}


public void setDummy(final BarType dummy) {
    this.dummyField = dummy;
}

public void setDummy(final String dummy) {
    this.dummyField = dummy;
}
```

the issue is that i can not deserialize correctly the schema (SCH1), instead I receive the :

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Conflicting setter definitions for property    "dummy": com.hybris.api.poc.SimplePojo#setDummy(1 params) vs com.hybris.api.poc.SimplePojo#setDummy(1 params)
```

I was trying to use the @JsonCreator, and @JsonDeserialize but no luck it seems that i can not have two (non primitive) override setters

```
  @JsonDeserialize( builder = FooType.FooTypeBuilder.class)
@JsonCreator
public void setDummy(final FooType dummy) {
    this.dummyField = dummy;
}

/**
 * Type specific setter for #dummy;
 *
 * @param dummy a reference to be set for #dummy
 */
@JsonDeserialize( builder = BarType.BarTypeBuilder.class )
@JsonCreator
public void setDummy(final BarType dummy) {
    this.dummyField = dummy;
}
```

Can you hint me where I should the solution or am i breaking some principal concept ?

Comment: I would move each specific setter in the specific class

Answer (score 1):

I do think you are breaking some principal concept there.  For this type of scenario, having a base abstract class with JsonTypeInfo and JsonSubTypes annotations to describe your sub-object would probably be preferred.  If you absolutely need the ability to set the three types via setDummy(...), would this work for you?

Replace:

```
public void setDummy(final FooType dummy) {
    this.dummyField = dummy;
}
public void setDummy(final BarType dummy) {
    this.dummyField = dummy;
}
public void setDummy(final String dummy) {
    this.dummyField = dummy;
}
```

With:

```
@JsonDeserialize( using = DummyDeserializer.class )
public void setDummy(final Object dummy) {
    // If you really need to restrict to the three types, throw exception here
    if (! (dummy instanceof FooType || dummy instanceof BarType || dummy instanceof String) ) {
        throw new Exception("Cannot setDummy dummy!");
    }
    this.dummyField = dummy;
}
```

This would require you to do the deserialization manually for all three classes in your DummyBuilder, but should solve your multi-setters problem.  I've not tried to implement this, but think it works.

Comment: This just moves the checking logic to the dummy builder which wouldn't be so dummy after all - I think I got it sorted out - that no magic will actually choose the proper type.×Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes×Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes×Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes

Answer (score 1):

No, without inheritance structure Jackson has no way of automatically determining intended type during deserialization. If they did share the same base type, you could use `@JsonTypeInfo` to indicate how type id is included (usually as a property); and have a single setter (or creator property).

Otherwise you can not have conflicting setters (i.e. more than one with types that are not related to each other by sub-typing).